# For an arbitrary continuous curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n$, does the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_0^1\gamma(t)\wedge d\gamma(t)$ exist?

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration, plane-curves, stieltjes-integral, winding-number

We consider sums of the form

$$\sum_{i=1}^m\gamma(t_i^*)\wedge\Big(\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})\Big),$$

where $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n$ is a continuous function, and

$$0=t_0\leq t_1^*\leq t_1\leq t_2^*\leq t_2\leq\cdots\leq t_{m-1}\leq t_m^*\leq t_m=1$$

is a tagged partition of the unit interval, and $\wedge$ is the exterior product. As the norm of the partition $\max_i|t_i-t_{i-1}|\to0$, do these sums converge?

In particular (taking $n=2$), if $x,y:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ are the coordinates of a plane curve, does

$$\int\big(x\,dy-y\,dx\big)$$

exist? This ought to be twice the area between the origin and the curve. Note, we can't break this into two integrals

$$\left(\int x\,dy\right)-\left(\int y\,dx\right)$$

because these may not exist. [Continuous function need not be Riemann-Stieltjes integrable if $\alpha$ is not monotone.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365375/continuous-function-need-not-be-riemann-stieltjes-integrable-if-alpha-is-not)

Maybe a space-filling curve would be a counter-example.

Comment: in the $n=2$ case, with $a$ sufficiently large, and with $\gamma(t)=(t\cos(t^{-a}), t\sin(t^{-a}))$, the integral doesn't seem to converge

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @user8268 (setting $a=2$ and replacing $t$ with $\sqrt t$), and as a modification of the linked answer, take the spiral curve

$$x=\sqrt t\sin1/t,\quad y=\sqrt t\cos1/t.$$

Let the tag points be $t_i^*=t_i$ to simplify:

$$x_i^*\big(y_i-y_{i-1}\big)-y_i^*\big(x_i-x_{i-1}\big)=x_{i-1}y_i-x_iy_{i-1}$$
$$=\sqrt{t_it_{i-1}}\sin\left(\frac1{t_{i-1}}-\frac1{t_i}\right).$$

(By continuity, when $t=0$ also $x=y=0$, so the first term in the Riemann sum is $x_0y_1-x_1y_0=0$.)

Suppose the norm of the partition is $\delta>0$, so $t_{i-1}\geq t_i-\delta$. To satisfy this restriction, fix the right half of the partition, where $t\geq\sqrt{2\delta/\pi}$, and for the left half of the partition take $t=2/(k\pi)$ for integers $k$ (in a finite but increasing range, including at least some $k\geq2/(\pi\delta)$ in consideration of the partition point $t=0$). So for $t\leq\sqrt{2\delta/\pi}$ we have

$$\frac1{t_{i-1}}-\frac1{t_i}=\frac\pi2$$
$$t_i-t_{i-1}=\frac\pi2t_it_{i-1}\leq\frac\pi2t_i^2\leq\delta$$

as required. The right half of the Riemann sum is fixed, and the left half is

$$\sum_k\sqrt{\frac2{k\pi}\frac2{(k+1)\pi}}\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)$$
$$\geq\sum_k\frac2{(k+1)\pi}$$

which can be made arbitrarily large. Hence, the integral doesn't exist.

---

Surprisingly, even if the curve is on the unit circle, the integral (which ought to be proportional to the winding number) may not exist.

$$x=\cos\phi(t),\quad y=\sin\phi(t)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^m(x_{i-1}y_i-y_{i-1}x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^m\sin\big(\phi(t_i)-\phi(t_{i-1})\big)$$

Such a sum is just what defines $\int_0^1\sin(d\phi(t))$. Since $d\phi$ is small (by uniform continuity of $\phi$, as the partition's norm is small), this integral ought to be $\int_0^1d\phi(t)=\phi(1)-\phi(0)$. In other words we should have $\int_0^1(\sin(d\phi(t))-d\phi(t))=0$. But it is not. Considering $\sin\theta-\theta\approx-\tfrac16\theta^3$, I was led to ask [whether $\int_0^1(d\phi(t))^3=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4819680/for-an-arbitrary-continuous-function-f-is-the-stieltjes-integral-int-01df), and found a counter-example, which will also work here:

$$\phi(t)=\frac4{3\sqrt3}\sqrt[3]t\Big(\sin\tfrac13\tau/t-\tfrac12\sin\tfrac23\tau/t\Big).$$

Again using reciprocals of integers as partition points, three terms in the sum will be

$$\sin\left(\phi\left(\frac1{3k}\right)-\phi\left(\frac1{3k+1}\right)\right)+\sin\left(\phi\left(\frac1{3k+1}\right)-\phi\left(\frac1{3k+2}\right)\right)+\sin\left(\phi\left(\frac1{3k+2}\right)-\phi\left(\frac1{3k+3}\right)\right)$$
$$=\sin\left(0-\frac1{(3k+1)^{1/3}}\right)+\sin\left(\frac1{(3k+1)^{1/3}}-\frac{-1}{(3k+2)^{1/3}}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{-1}{(3k+2)^{1/3}}-0\right)$$
$$=\sin\left(\frac1{(3k+1)^{1/3}}\right)\left(-1+\cos\left(\frac1{(3k+2)^{1/3}}\right)\right)+\left(-1+\cos\left(\frac1{(3k+1)^{1/3}}\right)\right)\sin\left(\frac1{(3k+2)^{1/3}}\right)$$
$$=-\frac12\sin\left(\frac1{(3k+1)^{1/3}}\right)\sin^2\left(\frac12\frac1{(3k+2)^{1/3}}\right)-\frac12\sin^2\left(\frac12\frac1{(3k+1)^{1/3}}\right)\sin\left(\frac1{(3k+2)^{1/3}}\right),$$

and since $\sin\theta\geq\tfrac12\theta$ when $\theta>0$ is small enough, this is

$$\leq-\frac1{64}\frac1{(3k+1)^{1/3}}\frac1{(3k+2)^{2/3}}-\frac1{64}\frac1{(3k+1)^{2/3}}\frac1{(3k+2)^{1/3}}$$
$$\leq-\frac1{64}\frac1{(3k+2)^{1/3}}\frac1{(3k+2)^{2/3}}-\frac1{64}\frac1{(3k+2)^{2/3}}\frac1{(3k+2)^{1/3}}$$
$$=-\frac1{32}\frac1{(3k+2)}.$$

Thus the sum is unbounded below.

What's happening geometrically is that we're inscribing tiny obtuse triangles in the circle, and somehow making their areas add up.

---

The unit square is no better. Using the same partition points and function $\phi$ from the previous section, let

$$(x,y)=\begin{cases}(1,\;1+\phi(t)),\quad\phi(t)\leq0\\(1-\phi(t),\;1),\quad\phi(t)\geq0\end{cases}$$

so three terms $x_{i-1}y_i-y_{i-1}x_i$ in the sum will be

$$(1)\cdot\left(1+\frac{-1}{(3k+2)^{1/3}}\right)-(1)\cdot(1)\\+(1)\cdot(1)-\left(1+\frac{-1}{(3k+2)^{1/3}}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{(3k+1)^{1/3}}\right)\\+\left(1-\frac{1}{(3k+1)^{1/3}}\right)\cdot(1)-(1)\cdot(1)$$
$$=-\frac1{(3k+1)^{1/3}(3k+2)^{1/3}}$$
$$\leq-\frac1{(3k+2)^{2/3}}$$

and again the sum is unbounded below, since $\sum_k1/k^{2/3}=\infty$.